# App control another app

Tags: remote-control, application-autoupdate

I have a special scenario in which I should be able to update an app without getting any access to the phone. So I think of another app (something like a boot loader for the original app) which is installed side by side. So my question is whether an app can stop another app, update it, and start it back or is it completely out of question for a non-rooted phone?

Comment: Are you authorized to do such activity, did the user allow or company/business required?

Comment: Both apps are done by me, so I can take any permission I want

Comment: Can you get access to that phone for at least once?

Comment: yes, for the first time when i put into a kiosk kind of thing

Comment: If you're looking for an end-user solution, you can use SecureTask plugin (needs to be set as a Device Owner) with Tasker and optionally, with IntentTask as well. The point comes down to having one of your apps be set as Device owner to silently install/remove/start apps without root access.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using consumer devices, one option is to use Android for Work or other Enterprise Mobile Management software which supports Android.

See: https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements?api=clouddpx#35-silent-app-distribution

`IT admins can silently distribute work apps on users' devices without any user interaction.`

Or look at this StackOverflow post: [PackageInstaller "Silent install and uninstall of apps by Device Owner” - Android M Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32473158/295004) which is off-topic for this group.